# Can I study Fine Arts at the age of 26/27

Tags: undergraduate, fine-performing-arts

I am Indian and I don't know , is there any possibilities to join Fine arts colleges at the age of 26/27. My background is Bachelor of Science and working in a small IT company.But I am not happy with my current situation.I would like to change the scope , Can I start over again in Fine arts? Because , I am still a good painter.And I want to be a good artist.From my childhood everyone use to say ,I paint awesome.
Apart from that, I love paining still now , and I want to study more in this field.
Is it possible ? please help.I have none in my life to guide me.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! Unfortunately, this question isn't really on topic here... this forum focuses on graduate-level life, not undergraduate.

Comment: There are plenty of resources online to learn Fine Arts, I don't think going into college specifically is necessary. What you should do is try to make your way slowly into Fine Arts while staying at your position, and afterwards take slowly steps toward being an artist rather than an IT worker.

Comment: I decided to respond below because Art has a different slant when looked at via academia filter as compared to most other topics.

Comment: @eykanal ,Pardon me , if i did something wrong, In India ,after school is called under graduation , means If I am seeking for graduation degree , I shall be called undergraduate. Is that you taking about ? graduate-level life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** yes you can. The question should be: Should you?

Art is very difficult to live from. That's why many successful artists not only exhibit a significant dose of obsession, but ideally also some marketing skills, patience, strategic thinking, charisma. Yes, and luck, and not in small doses.

Note that one thing I didn't mention as requirement was talent - that, of course, goes without saying.

So, the prudent way is to keep your day job as a computer developer and develop your arts skills as a hobby and, when you have broken enough ground you will have some opportunities to participate at minor, later bigger exhibitions before deciding about taking the plunge.

Alternatively, you could consider taking advantage of your computer skills to combine your artistic ambition with computer-based art creation and/or marketing. There are quite a few artists who used the internet very successfully to become known and appreciated.

Doing a proper art degree, I suspect, would be more of interest for people going into art theory, art critic, museum curation, gallery management, and, especially if you start so late, I am not sure it is the right route for someone like you who seems to be interested in *producing* art rather than analysing/managing/marketing it - but of course, there may be very good arts schools in your potential target areas which would raise your levels of skills, we cannot judge that.

An alternative would be to find some arts master in your area and take lessons.

On the whole, leaving a paying day job for studying art is a very risky route. It's, of course, not impossible, but you need to be aware of the risks. Many artists end up *not* doing what they intended to do in the first place, even if they are very talented and have several of the skills above. By the time you finish your studies and decide that art does not work for you, your computer skills will be outdated, so this is what you have to take into account.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your kind advise. Yes basically its risky though. I shall prefer to make an earning option beside it to survive and I would like to stay with some people , like you, give such a wonderful advice ,forever .